# How to show menu on the all pages Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.5

I have the main template `home.blade.php` that contains section inside which is put another content files.

In this file I have left sidebar menu.

Also I have custom `class Menu` to displaying menu items.

Whete to call this custom class/service that menu will be showed on the all pages in project?

I dont want to create instance of `class Menu` in each controller classes.

Comment: Check out this Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is Laravel’s **View::share()** method. You can instantiate the class in your AppServiceProvider class and make the variable available to all your views https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: What is better to use: View Composers or Share View?  Do support both singlton model?

Comment: The are sort of interchangeable (I use share() for everything), but view composers seem more suited to class instantiation so that is probably your best option.

Comment: Can you share an example of code, how to write this and use? Cause there is not enough info in docs

Answer (score 1):

create a seperate file menu.blade.php and write menu code in this file, 
include menu.blade.php in other files like this. 
use this to extend code

@extends('menu')